# VBA code doesn't replace a string inside FormulaArray

Tags: vba, excel

A column in my Excel has a long function in `FormulaArray` format in the VBA code. My VBA code copies this long array function to the cell in this column.

Since the characters in the array function are more than 255, I broke down the formula string into two pieces as:

`StrForm`is the string for the whole formula, `StrInner1` is the first inner piece of this `StrForm` and `StrInner2` is the second inner piece of `StrForm`.

`tmp1` and `tmp2`are two temporary parameters, and I replace them with `StrInner1` and `StrInner2` in the next step.

I don't get any error, this code copies the `StrForm` successfully to the cell `D2`. But it doesn't replace the `"tmp1"` and `;"tmp2"` with `StrInner1` and `StrInner2`. Can anyone see what is wrong with this cause I can't...

```
Sub test()
    Dim StrForm, StrInner1, StrInner2 As String

    StrInner1 = "$A$2=Sheet2!B2;$A$3=Sheet2!B2;$A$4=Sheet2!B2;$A$5=Sheet2!B2;$A$6=Sheet2!B2;$A$7=Sheet2!B2;$A$8=Sheet2!B2"        

    StrInner2 = ";$A$9=Sheet2!B2;$A$10=Sheet2!B2;$A$11=Sheet2!B2;$A$12=Sheet2!B2;$A$13=Sheet2!B2;$A$14=Sheet2!B2;$A$15=Sheet2!B2" 

    StrForm = "=IF(IF(OR(""tmp1"";""tmp2"");Sheet2!A2;"""")=0;"""";IF(OR(""tmp1"";""tmp2"");Sheet2!A2;""""))"

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").FormulaLocal = StrForm   

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").FormulaArray = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Formula
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Replace What:="""tmp1""", Replacement:=StrInner1, lookat:=xlPart
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Replace What:=";""tmp2""", Replacement:=StrInner2, lookat:=xlPart

    ' StrInner1 and StrInner2 will be next to each other, so I also remove the semicolon between tmp1 and tmp2
End Sub
```

Comment: we have long moved away from 16bit computing. String in VBA should accept more than 256 char :)

Comment: @krishKM when you send the formula with regular `Formula`, then over 255 character is not problem. but it is something special with `FormulaArray`, it gives error. Maybe because array function is a multidimensional calculation and just to limit this multidimensional calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change those two lines:

```
StrInner1 = "$A$2=Sheet2!B2,$A$3=Sheet2!B2,$A$4=Sheet2!B2,$A$5=Sheet2!B2,$A$6=Sheet2!B2,$A$7=Sheet2!B2,$A$8=Sheet2!B2"

StrInner2 = "$A$9=Sheet2!B2,$A$10=Sheet2!B2,$A$11=Sheet2!B2,$A$12=Sheet2!B2,$A$13=Sheet2!B2,$A$14=Sheet2!B2,$A$15=Sheet2!B2"
```

You are replacing text in `FormulaArray` and it is not local version, so comma is always field separator.

Also change:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Replace What:="""tmp2""", Replacement:=StrInner2, lookat:=xlPart
```

Same problem - you are trying to replace `;` and it does not exist. Best way to avoid it is to remove it from search pattern and from `StrInner2`, simply replace the placeholder.

Interesting thing is that when you replace text in `FormulaArray` and the result is not a valid formula, there is no error message, but `FormulaArray` is left unchanged

Comment: thanks a lot :) i am very surprised that why Microsoft developed Excel different for different languages. It should be universal comma or semicolon.